# Sitemap with SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, seo, portalsitemapprovider

I am using SharePoint 2013 enterprise version. I have full crawled Search Service. I have also activated Search Engine Sitemap feature. I also successfully run the time job for the sitemap.

My website is https://www.website.com and two language variation 
https://www.website.com/en and https://www.website.com/ar

My issue is that where I will find the generated sitemap files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Waqas for your help, I found the issue my Search Service Application was not associated to my Web Application due to that sitemap was not generating. Once I have associated all starts working good.

Answer (score 2):

he sitemap is located at the root level site collection. The url to access the sitemap is `http://<WebApp>/sites/<SiteColl>/sitemap.xml`. This file contains the location of actual sitemap and that is `http://<WebApp>/sites/<SiteColl>/sitemap0.xml`. The content of the sitemap file is like:[image]

read complete: https://mysharepointlearnings.wordpress.com/2013/10/20/sitemaps-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: I know that article already but can you tell me based on my question URL where it can be ?

Comment: https://www.website.com/sitemap.xml and https://www.website.com/sitemap0.xml try these

Comment: I tried but I could not find it

Comment: Is it path based site collection or hnsc? Is it root level site collection in the web application?

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: Are you meet the pre req mentioned in the article, search, anonymous access etc

Comment: How you create site collection? Host name site collection with fqdn URL or it is root level site collection as path based?

Comment: i created with fqdn URL